# param is missing or the value is empty: item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**items_controller.rb**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @items = Item.all
    render text: @items.map{ |i| "#{i.name}: #{i.price}" }.join('<br/>')
  end

  def create
    item_params = params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :price, :real, :weight)
    @item = Item.create(item_params)
    render text: "#{@item.id}: #{@item.name}(#{!@item.new_record?})"
  end

end
```

> error :  param is missing or the value is empty: item
>
> Rails.root: E:/work/my_store_2
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/controllers/items_controller.rb:9:in `create' Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"name"=>"car1",  "description"=>"good car",  "price"=>"500000", 
>   "weight"=>"0",  "real"=>"1"}

**console**

```
Started GET "/items/create?name=car1&description=good+car&price=500000&weight=0&real=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-18 21:25:39 +0300
Processing by ItemsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"name"=>"car1", "description"=>"good car", "price"=>"500000", "weight"=>"0", "real"=>"1"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: item):
  app/controllers/items_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

**where is my mistake?**

Comment: please post your routes... the create should be post and not get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you do `params.require(:item)` it requires that the `item` parameter exist. So, that `create` action is expecting something like this as parameters: `{ "item" => {"name"=>"car1", "description"=>"good car", "price"=>"500000", "weight"=>"0", "real"=>"1"} }`

You are missing the `item` root key.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the 'item' on your form.  Add a field with id="item".